# Mutex map data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, asynchronous, concurrency, mutex

## the problem

- I have a directory `D` that I want to put `(K, V)` pairs into
- `void save(K, V)` saves file name `K` with contents `V` to directory `D`

  - Has "fire and forget" semantics - function may return before it actually saves the file to disk
- Directory `D` is a field of the class `C` defining the `save` function
- Calls to `void save(K, V)` should run concurrently

  - Using `tbb::task` for concurrency
  - No two file writes for the same key can be run concurrently
  - That is, if two threads call `save(K, V1)` and `save(K, V2)` at the same time, the result should be a file in `D` named `K` that has contents equal to *either* `V1` *or* `V2` (but not corrupted)

## planned approach

- Pick a hash function `H` that maps `K` to a `std::size_t`
- Pick an integer `N > 1`
- Give class `C` an array of mutexes `tbb::mutex mutex_map[N]`
- `void save(K, V)` waits to acquire a lock on `mutex_map[H(K) % N]` to perform its file write

## questions

- Is this a sensible approach?
- Can you think of an alternative that might have advantages over this?
- Is there some `tbb` data structure that already encapsulates this concept of a mutex map?

  - Think something like a `std::map<TKey, tbb::mutex>` but where the interface gives the appearance of every possible key simultaneously having an associated mutex.

Comment: You might want to use an atomic flag instead of a mutex if you don't care about two concurrent writes, or one write coming in while another is in progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a very sensible approach.  I can not think of an alternative (except for trivial alternatives like using `std::mutex` instead of `tbb:mutex`.)

You should pick `N` large compared to the number of mutexes that you think will be simultaneously locked.  The [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) says that if you expect to have *k* threads simultaneously trying to lock then the probability of having at least one spurious hash collision is greater than 50% until you get `N >` *o(k<sup>2</sup>)*.

I don't know of a tbb data structure that is like a map of mutexes.  But *internally* I believe that tbb::malloc uses the trick you are suggesting (threads are randomly assigned to independent malloc data-structures), and the tbb::concurrent_hash_map is implemented such that there is a mutex per hash-bucket.

Answer (score 0):

## my implementation for posterity

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <tbb/mutex.h> //could of course use std::mutex instead, if available

template <typename Key, typename Hash = std::hash<Key>>
class mutex_map
{
public:
    typedef Key key_type;
    typedef tbb::mutex value_type;
    static const std::size_t default_bucket_count = 16;

private:
    std::vector<value_type> mutexes;
    Hash hash;

public:
    mutex_map(
        std::size_t bucket_count = default_bucket_count,
        const Hash& hash = Hash())
        : hash(hash)
    {
        mutexes.resize(bucket_count);
    }

    std::size_t size() const
    {
        return mutexes.size();
    }

    value_type& get(const Key& key)
    {
        auto n = hash(key) % size();
        n += (n < 0) * size();
        return mutexes[n];
    }
};
```

Comment: std::mutex cannot be moved, so I just used a simple array instead of vector. Thanks for the idea though!